# Jump Table not found in Assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, switch-statement, jump-table

I'm learning Assembly. I wrote the below c program containing switch case, created the object file(gcc -o filename filename.c), then took the object dump. But I didn't find the Labels and jump tables in the object dump.

Can anybody tell me why the jump table is not getting generated ? Like the ones mention here
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012011/switch-case-assembly-level-code)

## Code

C file

```
int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int n = 9, z = 99 , p = 999;
  switch( i ) 
    {
      case -1:
      n++;
      printf("value n=%d",n);
      break;
      case 0 :
      z++;
      printf("value z=%d",z);
      break;
      case 1 :
      p++;
      printf("value p=%d",p);
      break;
      case 2 :
      p++;
      printf("value p=%d",p);
      break;
      case 3 :
      p++;
      printf("value p=%d",p);
      break;
      case 4 :
      p++;
      printf("value p=%d",p);
      break;
      case 5 :
      p++;
      printf("value p=%d",p);
      break;

   }
  printf("Values n=%d z=%d p=%d \n",n,z,p);
  return 0;
}
```

Below is the main section

```
0804841d <main>:
 804841d:   55                      push   %ebp
 804841e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048420:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048423:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
 8048426:   c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
 804842d:   00 
 804842e:   c7 44 24 10 09 00 00    movl   $0x9,0x10(%esp)
 8048435:   00 
 8048436:   c7 44 24 14 63 00 00    movl   $0x63,0x14(%esp)
 804843d:   00 
 804843e:   c7 44 24 18 e7 03 00    movl   $0x3e7,0x18(%esp)
 8048445:   00 
 8048446:   8b 44 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 804844a:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 804844d:   83 f8 06                cmp    $0x6,%eax
 8048450:   0f 87 cb 00 00 00       ja     8048521 <main+0x104>
 8048456:   8b 04 85 1c 86 04 08    mov    0x804861c(,%eax,4),%eax
 804845d:   ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
 804845f:   83 44 24 10 01          addl   $0x1,0x10(%esp)
 8048464:   8b 44 24 10             mov    0x10(%esp),%eax
 8048468:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 804846c:   c7 04 24 e0 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485e0,(%esp)
 8048473:   e8 78 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048478:   e9 a4 00 00 00          jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 804847d:   83 44 24 14 01          addl   $0x1,0x14(%esp)
 8048482:   8b 44 24 14             mov    0x14(%esp),%eax
 8048486:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 804848a:   c7 04 24 eb 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485eb,(%esp)
 8048491:   e8 5a fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048496:   e9 86 00 00 00          jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 804849b:   83 44 24 18 01          addl   $0x1,0x18(%esp)
 80484a0:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80484a4:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80484a8:   c7 04 24 f6 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485f6,(%esp)
 80484af:   e8 3c fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 80484b4:   eb 6b                   jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 80484b6:   83 44 24 18 01          addl   $0x1,0x18(%esp)
 80484bb:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80484bf:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80484c3:   c7 04 24 f6 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485f6,(%esp)
 80484ca:   e8 21 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 80484cf:   eb 50                   jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 80484d1:   83 44 24 18 01          addl   $0x1,0x18(%esp)
 80484d6:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80484da:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80484de:   c7 04 24 f6 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485f6,(%esp)
 80484e5:   e8 06 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 80484ea:   eb 35                   jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 80484ec:   83 44 24 18 01          addl   $0x1,0x18(%esp)
 80484f1:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80484f5:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80484f9:   c7 04 24 f6 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485f6,(%esp)
 8048500:   e8 eb fd ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048505:   eb 1a                   jmp    8048521 <main+0x104>
 8048507:   83 44 24 18 01          addl   $0x1,0x18(%esp)
 804850c:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048510:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048514:   c7 04 24 f6 85 04 08    movl   $0x80485f6,(%esp)
 804851b:   e8 d0 fd ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048520:   90                      nop
 8048521:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048525:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
 8048529:   8b 44 24 14             mov    0x14(%esp),%eax
 804852d:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048531:   8b 44 24 10             mov    0x10(%esp),%eax
 8048535:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048539:   c7 04 24 01 86 04 08    movl   $0x8048601,(%esp)
 8048540:   e8 ab fd ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048545:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 804854a:   c9                      leave  
 804854b:   c3                      ret    
 804854c:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 804854e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Below is the .rodata section

```
Disassembly of section .rodata:

080485d8 <_fp_hw>:
 80485d8:   03 00                   add    (%eax),%eax
    ...
```

Can anybody let me know why this is behaving like this? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you look at what's at 804861c?

Comment: Apart from what @harold asks, there is no guarantee a compiler will generate a jump table for your code.

Comment: If your compiler has it, don't use a disassembler but use an option like `-S` directly to produce the assembler. Usually this is far more readable since it still has labels and not just jump addresses.

Comment: @harold Sorry if I misunderstood u ...are you asking me to use gdb to check the address 804861c ?

Comment: @user3538267 yes, and check it as dwords, trying to disassemble it will be useless.

Comment: @JensGustedt I used "gcc -o filename filename.c" to create the object file and "objdump -D objFileName "for the above out put. After reading your comment I tried with "objdump -S objFileName" but still I didn't find any jump table entries

Comment: No, it isn't an `objdump` parameter that I meant, sorry if that was not clear. I meant the compiler option. `gcc -S filename.c` should give you much nicer assembler.

Comment: @JensGustedt thanks for help. but through -S switch we can get .s file (asm program) . Hence can I say, in binary there is no symbol table ? its only there in compiled asm program .

Comment: Sure it is there, but there is just no symbol anymore that points to it, since this is not necessary. As is described in the answer, the symbol table is just refered to by its address, `0x804861c`.

Answer (score 1):

Your jump table is located at address `0x804861c`. If you dump this address, I'm pretty sure, you'll find the values `0x804845f`, `0x804847d`, `0x804849b`, etc. since these values correspond to the addresses of the branches of the switch statement. 
What happens is that first it is ensured that the value of `i` (`0x1c(%esp)`)is between 0 and 6 (and jump if above, `ja`, to last printf) and if it is between, uses its value multiplied by 4 (sizeof addresses on your architecture) as an offset into the jump table (`0x804861c(,%eax,4),%eax`).

I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, or what you're trying to achieve, but as @Jens Gustedt pointed out, you should use the `-S` switch if you want to observe the assembly generated.

Additionally, beware that your code can easily be optimised by the compiler, i.e. as soon as you use the `-O` switch your assembly will probably shrink down to the last printf and the return statement, since the whole code execution can be predicted and useless parts can be omitted.

Comment: Actually the code ensures that `i` is between `0` and `6` (@ `804844a`) by adding 1 to the *original* range -1..5.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, you're right. Updated the post to reflect this, thanks!

Comment: @grasbueschel can you tell me what do you mean by dumping the address 0x804861c, what exactly do I need to do? I just want to see how a simple c program with switch statements gets converted to jump table

Comment: @user3538267 compile with the `-S` switch. The generated assembly will be much clearer than the compiled version, i.e. no addresses to dump, just code to read...