# what is Table manipulation and multiple-way branching in assembly-language

Tags: assembly

I couldn't find my answer in google, I want some basic information about "**Table manipulation** and **multiple-way branching** in assembly-language" with an example

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: Seems like OP is quoting from section 11.3 (Instruction Formats) of "Computer Organization and Architecture" by William Stallings, as found [here](https://archive.org/stream/ComputerOrganizationAndArchitecture/Computer%20Organization%20And%20Architecture_djvu.txt).

Comment: "multiple-way branching" is probably a jump table, e.g. a `switch` implementation.

Comment: @MargaretBloom
even I don't know the context that's why I asked it here

Comment: @RuudHelderman
Yes I am reading that book (o_o)

Comment: @OmarKarbasi The book was exactly the context MargaretBloom (and probably others) were looking for; mentioning your sources is also part of asking a good question on SO.

Comment: @RuudHelderman
Thank you for mentioning 
sorry that I am noob in this site, didn't know how to ask question
now I started reading the rules of asking questions

Comment: what assembly language were you interested in, is this a homework question or some other such task specifically, or just a curiosity?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012011/switch-case-assembly-level-code.  Could even mark this a duplicate, but it's not a good SO question in the first place and should probably just be deleted.  You have to know some basics to ask a question, because "teach me about X" isn't a good question.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    switch(x&7)
    {
        case 0: return(x<<1); 
        case 1: return(2); 
        case 2: return(x>>1); 
        case 3: return(x+x); 
        case 4: return(x&3); 
        case 5: return(x+(x<<1)); 
        case 6: return(5); 
        case 7: return(x+x+x); 
    }
}
```

one implementation.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2003007    and r3, r0, #7
   4:   e2433001    sub r3, r3, #1
   8:   e3530006    cmp r3, #6
   c:   979ff103    ldrls   pc, [pc, r3, lsl #2]
  10:   ea000006    b   30 <fun+0x30>
  14:   00000040    andeq   r0, r0, r0, asr #32
  18:   00000050    andeq   r0, r0, r0, asr r0
  1c:   00000030    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsr r0
  20:   00000048    andeq   r0, r0, r8, asr #32
  24:   00000038    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr r0
  28:   00000058    andeq   r0, r0, r8, asr r0
  2c:   00000038    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr r0
  30:   e1a00080    lsl r0, r0, #1
  34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  38:   e0800080    add r0, r0, r0, lsl #1
  3c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  40:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
  44:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  48:   e2000003    and r0, r0, #3
  4c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  50:   e1a000a0    lsr r0, r0, #1
  54:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  58:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
  5c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the program counter is computed programatically so based on inputs and can land at any one of those places based on the input and math. (nice catch on the optimization I was trying not to have any direct duplicate cases, but didnt try that hard)

Comment: as jester said it is probably a jump table from a switch.  Out of context what other way could you do multi-way branching?  either mathmatically produce a program counter for instruction sets where you can do that or a jump table for instruction sets that allow that (or as in this case a combination of the two).  Right, what else could those words mean?

Comment: this is a give them a fish answer, I get beat up whenever a teach them to fish here...